# 220-240 V 50 hz Sony Bravia TV for use in 110/120v 60 hz power

Tags: electrical, television

I just moved back to US from Europe and brought my Sony Bravia 65" (KD-65AF8) TV back with me. I thought I had checked tag on back to make sure it was compatible before bringing it back but obviously I was mistaken.  Bought this TV new in early 2020 (2018 model) and it wasnt cheap so if possible I want to use it.  The voltage I am not worried about as I have a step-up transformer its the frequency that I am worried about. Will using it at 60 hz damage anything or pose an electrical/fire hazard?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about consumer electronics. Unfortunately that isn't "home improvement" per the definition on this site. See the [help].

Answer (score 3):

On electronic loads, the 50/60Hz is vanishingly unlikely to be a problem.  It's a problem for motor loads where the motor is now spinning 20% faster. A clock won't keep time.

> The voltage I am not worried about as I have a step-up transformer

Unless you bought it at a quality retail shop such as Wickes, Home Store, Redoute, etc., this is probably cheap Cheese pile of garbage that will a) burn your house down and b) result in insurance claim denial.

If you're using it in North America, choose a **UL-Listed** transformer. You won't find that on eBay, wish.com, Amazon Marketplace, Banggood, DealExtreme, Aliexpress and all the other usual "flea market tier" pushers of dangerous trash.

You can get native 240V right to the TV with a breaker, cheap #14 Romex (or #12 if you have that lying around). Heck, you could even bring this in *behind the TV* on a wall-mount TV if you're into that sort of thing.

Here's a socket comparison, either of the two on the right will suffice and it uses the same junction boxes and cables as normal wiring, it just lands [on a double-wide breaker](https://youtu.be/jMmUoZh3Hq4?t=441).

[image]

If, by chance, the existing living room circuits are setup as a "MWBC" (Multi-Wire Branch Circuit or shared neutral) this could happen as easily as changing a socket. MWBCs bring both legs of power to the junction box, and 120V outlets grab 1 leg and neutral. They even make a 120/240V outlet, 1 socket of each.

Comment: This. It is very much possible to actually get 240V in the home if you know what you're doing, and it's legit.